# OpenXML alternative for Microsoft Office Interops "SelectContentControlsByTitle" in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, office-interop

The project in which I'm involved has a requirement of generating Word documents. 
Initially, I used Interop to achieve this. But since Interop requires the clients to  have Office installed on their machines, I switched over to OpenXML instead.

Interop has a nice method for getting Content Controls by title "SelectContentControlsByTitle", is there any alternative to this in OpenXML?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @gausselem, There is no direct method for getting contentcontrol by title in openXML SDK, instead of that , you have to iterate each and every sdtBlock in the document to get the text of sdtBlock (ie, ContentControl).

Comment: Hi, yes I solved it in that way. But I really wanted to skip the iteration part, because we have to generate up to 50 reports. Although, OpenXML is much faster than Interrop so it payed of.